# Neumann series as an integral operator

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, operator-theory, differential-operators

Let $D$ be the derivative operator, and set
$$T:=\sum_{n=0}^\infty D^n. $$
It is [known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series#Properties) that under certain conditions 
$$T=(Id-D)^{-1} .$$
Set $v=Tu$, applying $I-D$ to both sides, in this case, gives the ODE
$$v-v'=u $$
which can be solved for $v$ as follows
$$v=\mathrm{e}^x \left( C-\int \mathrm{e}^{-x} u(x) \mathrm{d} x \right),$$
where $C$ is a constant of integration, originating from the indefinite integral. At the same time we also have
$$v=Tu=\sum_{n=0}^\infty u^{(n)}(x), $$
so we seem to get
$$ \mathrm{e}^x \left( C-\int \mathrm{e}^{-x} u(x) \mathrm{d} x \right)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty u^{(n)}(x).$$
The left hand side is an infinite 1-parametric family of functions, while the right hand side is a concrete function, provided the series converges (e.g. the case where $u(x)$ is a polynomial).

My questions are: how does one settle this issue? Is the integral on the left hand side satisfying some initial/boundary condition? What is the value of $C$?

Thank you!

Comment: In general for a ODE like $v' - v = -u$ you need to apply the initial conditions to fix the value of $C$. For your case integrating $[v(x)e^{-x}]' = -u(x)e^{-x}$ over $[0,x]$ gives $v(x) = v(0) e^{x} - \int_0^x u(x') e^{x-x'}{\rm d}x'$.

Comment: What's with the hyperlink?

Comment: @Aweygan Oops, lol. That's not the right one. I'll fix it.

Comment: Yeah I thought something was fishy lol.  Now to the matter at hand, observe the first sentence in the properties tab of the linked page: Suppose $T$ is a bounded operator acting on the normed vector space $X$.  So to apply this result, we need to have a normed vector space $D$ acts on, and $D$ needs to be bounded.  Without this, the Neumann series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty D^k$ and $(I-D)^{-1}$ need not be equal.  Moreover, $(I-D)^{-1}$ may not make sense.